# Selecting :hover for multiple elements

Tags: css, hover

I have multiple images (`.entry`) on a page and want to add a button to each that is hidden and displays when the user hovers over the image. I did some research and found how to effect multiple elements when hovering over one. But I want to do the opposite: I want to shorthand my CSS `button {"display: block;"}` for the hover state of any of the images.

I tried:

1)

```
.entry01, .entry02, .entry03, .entry04, .entry05, .entry06, .entry07, .entry08, .entry09:hover button{
    display: block;
}
```

RESULT: Button only shows when I hover over the 9th image

2)

```
.entry01:hover, .entry02:hover, .entry03:hover, .entry04:hover, .entry05:hover, .entry06:hover, .entry07:hover, .entry08:hover, .entry09:hover button{
    display: block;
}
```

RESULT: Button only shows when I hover over the 9th image

I assume I can write it out for each individually but was hoping to learn a shorter way. I appreciate any ideas!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: To clarify: my buttons are in place for all images and display the way I want them to when set to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat `button` in each selector:

```
.entry01:hover button, .entry02:hover button, .entry03:hover button, ... {
    display: block;
}
```

Each comma-separated item is treated as a complete selector. If you use a preprocessor like LESS or SASS you may be able to simplify it.

A better solution would probably be to give all of them the same class, e.g.

```
<div class="entry entry01">...</div>
```

Then you can just use:

```
.entry:hover button {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! Went with the option of adding the additional .entry - WORKS Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new class to all you .entry(1-9) tags in your html code:

```
<div class="hover entry1></div>
<div class="hover entry2></div>
```

etc.

and now in your css file:

```
.hover:hover button{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<div class="entry">Image 1
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div class="entry">Image 2
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
</div>

.btn{display:none;}
.entry:hover button{display:block;}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/k0pggay1/